# I have created multiple dynamic select boxes in div with class=pricefield. I want to fetch all select boxes value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created dynamic select boxes in a div with `class=pricefield`. I want to fetch all the select boxes values which option is selected in each select boxes in jQuery.

```
<div class="pricefield">

     // Now all comes dynamically
     <label>first</label>
     <div class=""d-field>
     <select>
          <option value="100">first</option>
          <option value="200">secound</option>
          //may be more options
     </select>
     </div>

     <label>second</label>
     <div class=""d-field>
     <select>
          <option value="300">first</option>
          <option value="400">second</option>
          //Maybe more options
     </select>
     </div>
     // Maybe more select
</div>
```

.js code

```
jQuery('.pricefield select').each(jQuery(this).change(
    function(key,value){

        // It did not work.
        alert(jQuery(this).filter("option:selected").val());

        // It not worked, gives a blank value.
        alert(jQuery(this).val());

        // Key and value gives undefined.
        alert(key);
        alert(value);
    }
));
```

I want to sum all the values of selected options in each dropdown...

Comment: don't need to look for the option(s) , can just use `$(this).val()` in a `select`...returns same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write:

```
get_sum();
$('.pricefield select').change(function () {
    get_sum();
});
function get_sum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.pricefield select').each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).find("option:selected").val());
    });
    alert(sum);
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Se48w/)

Comment: Thanks ... but, it gives me 0 at alert(sum) ... and alert(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val()) it gives me undefined ...